# failed to receive data from hbase due to java net connection exception :Connection Refused in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

Working on Nifi with Hbase. In this i get data from Hbase, Using Gethbase processor and send data to Putfile processor in Nifi.But i get the error "failed to receive data from Hbase due to java net connection exception :Connection Refused" in Nifi .Any suggestions please

Answer (score 2):

You would need to ensure that the node where NiFi is running can communicate with ZooKeeper and all the HBase nodes.

GetHBase uses the HBaseClientService which has a property for the Configuration Resources. You would want to set your Configuration Resources to a comma-separated list of files containing the HBase configuration. These would typically be hbase-site.xml and core-site.xml, and these files would tell the processor where ZooKeeper is located.

Assuming you are running NiFi on a node where HBase is not running, you would copy the hbase-site.xml and core-site.xml from an HBase node, on to the node where NiFi is.

Comment: I am working on "Fun_With_Hbase.xml" Template. In this i will send data to hbase table, but i will not get data from hbase. I will get the "failed to receive data from hbase due to java net connection exception :Connection Refused" error in GetHbase Processor and In PutHbaseCell,PutHbaseJson Processor i got error Like This " Missing Row id failure, routing to failure ".